# Visual Studio issue pairing to Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using latest Visual Studio for Windows 17.4.2, connecting to my Mac having Xcode 14.1, I get this message when Pairing to Mac:

> The Xcode version installed on the Mac (14.1) is not compatible with
> this version of Visual Studio. This may cause unexpected warnings or
> errors when building and deploying iOS projects. Please install Xcode
> '13.3'. To download a specific version of Xcode, visit:
> https://developer.apple.com/downloads.

If I continue, no iOS simulators are available for debugging. And when trying to debug on my iPhone connected by wire the the Mac, I get a compiler error:

> fatal error: 'CHIP/CHIP.h' file not found

I have search the web. Only old articles appear from September. I have tried XCode 14.0 still, same issues.

Last resort was downloading XCode 13.4.1 that seems ton works. I can start simulation... Finally!

Is it really true that XCode 14 is yet not supported by Visual Studio?

Comment: is 17.4.2 the latest version of windows VS?

Comment: Yes it is. abcdef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be noted that the final builds of `Xcode 14.1` are ready for you to test on `Xamarin`, but they are not included in IDE (it is not supported yet in MAUI), you have to install the pkg files of [Xamarin.iOS](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/82c00e2b-6bfe-4450-8691-5cb8464c37dc/e67bae84054f6aa4e221ab7f63edf78a/xamarin.ios-16.1.1.27.pkg) and [Xamarin.Mac](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/82c00e2b-6bfe-4450-8691-5cb8464c37dc/34dcb22cccb6f364e64346f6812b0adc/xamarin.mac-9.0.0.27.pkg) to your Mac,refer to [Xcode 14.1 Support · Issue #16659 · xamarin/xamarin-macios](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16659).

> Is it really true that XCode 14 is yet not supported by Visual Studio?

`Xcode 14` is supported, and it is recommended that you use `Xcode 14.0` for now. The Xcode version in AppStore is Xcode14.1 currently, you can download Xcode 14.0 from the [downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) in the Apple Developer Portal.

Comment: But it really worries me that Visual Studio is not updated for latest xcode yet. Back in the good old Xamarin Forms days, Microsoft was always making sure to get visual studio updated to latest xcode version. But the focus on MAUI apparently made Microsoft lazy, not supporting the Xamarin ecosystem as otherwise promised.

Comment: If Microsoft is not going to update Visual Studio for latest xcode version going forward, they should at least have a support page, listing how to get up and running in regards to latest versions of XCode and Visual Studio versions.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. That would be more convenient to view the compatibility of Visual Studio and Xcode.

Comment: The real answer here is to stop using Xamarin in general. Aside from being horrible at everything, there are far better options like Flutter.